# How to feed TensorFlow Datasets into traning_x, training_y, testing_x,testing_y into Keras API?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

[TensorFlow Datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets) was a convent tool to utilize the datasets from the internet. However, I got confused about how to feed it into the Input layer in tensor flow Keras API. The dataset used was the [tensorflow dataset's emnist](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/emnist).

Here's what was known:

**Point 1**: Instead of the store the dataset into the memory, tensorflow database, warp around the tensorflow data module, preprocess the dataset on the hard drive, and use a pipeline(a class instance like object?) to feed the data into the python function. It does so with a [load function](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/load).

**Issue 1** "as_supervised":
However, there were two "different" load methods with or without "as_supervised" being on,

```
train_ds = tfds.load('mnist', split='train', as_supervised=True,shuffle_files=True)
ds = tfds.load('mnist', split='train', shuffle_files=True)
```

wherein the [tfds.load](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/load), this keyword was explained as

> bool, if True, the returned `tf. data.Dataset` will have a 2-tuple structure (input, label) according to builder.info.supervised_keys. If False, the default, the returned `tf.data.Dataset` will have a dictionary with all the features.

```
ds=ds.take(5)
for example in ds:  # example is `{'image': tf.Tensor, 'label': tf.Tensor}`
    image = example["image"]
    label = example["label"]
    print(type(image))
    print(image.shape,"label", label)
    plt.imshow(image) #np.array(inputs).reshape(28,28) maybe needed based on the compiler
    plt.show()
```

and

```
for inputs,targets in train_ds:
  print(type(inputs))
  print(inputs.shape,"label=",targets)
  plt.imshow(inputs)
  plt.show()
```

both returned

```
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>
(28, 28, 1) label tf.Tensor(2, shape=(), dtype=int64)
```

- a. so what's the point of using the **as_supervised** argument here? since the data was labeled by ds_info.supervised_keys(**tfds.core.DatasetInfo**) anyway?

**Issue 2**: In the [split and slice](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/splits) it provided a lot of commands to slit the training set and test set. Unfortunately, most of it didn't work. (Anaconda build with most recent modules) For example, the code

```
# The full `train` split and the full `test` split as two distinct datasets.
train_ds, test_ds = tfds.load('mnist', split=['train', 'test'])
```

resulted in a warning

> WARNING:absl:Warning: Setting shuffle_files=True because split=TRAIN and shuffle_files=None. This behavior will be deprecated on 2019-08-06, at which point shuffle_files=False will be the default for all splits.

which shouldn't be an issue.
However,

```
# The full `train` and `test` splits, interleaved together.
train_test_ds = tfds.load('mnist', split='train+test')

# From record 10 (included) to record 20 (excluded) of `train` split.
train_10_20_ds = tfds.load('mnist', split='train[10:20]')

# The first 10% of train split.
train_10pct_ds = tfds.load('mnist', split='train[:10%]')

# The first 10% of train + the last 80% of train.
train_10_80pct_ds = tfds.load('mnist', split='train[:10%]+train[-80%:]')
```

all returned error and a message

> "Invalid split train+test. Available splits are: ['test', 'train']"

where those two parameters were defined in the ds_info. But this meant one could no longer split the "train" into a training set, testing set, or restrict the training set to 10% of the entire 'train', a smaller size.

- c. Suppose that the load was meant only for the "train" section of emnist. How to divide the import into train_set and test_set? or restrict the train_set to be only 10% of the entire "train"?

**Issue 3**
The train_ds was a pipeline. Either with as_supervised or without, one needs to call in the specific elements in order to use them, either with tuple or with a dictionary:

```
input, target in train_ds
elem in ds: elem["image"] elem["label"]
```

But the model.fit in tensor flow require an input of

```
training_x(for input layer): N*(image size)
training_y(for the target) : N*(target size)
```

Either, the pipeline train_ds or ds was not that. Consider the nice load function in `keras.datasets` which split the training datasets into x_train and y_train automatically.

```
(x_train,y_train),(x_test,y_test)=tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
```

I thought about using a for loop to train the feed data from the pipeline into model 1 element by 1 element, but that's clearly not what's suppose to be done.
How to feed the train_ds or ds into the model. fit function?

Comment: About your issue 1, I believe it's an option that we've. And about your issue 2, in my run, I didn't encounter those errors, it works just fine.

Comment: For me, your issue 3 is a bit unclear.

Comment: @M.Innat Issue 2 It's only working for google colab but not in conda: ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\api_utils.py in disallow_positional_args_dec(fn, instance, args, kwargs)
     50     _check_no_positional(fn, args, ismethod, allowed=allowed)
     51     _check_required(fn, kwargs)
---> 52     return fn(*args, **kwargs)
     53 
     54   return disallow_positional_args_dec(wrapped)  # pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter

Comment: ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\splits.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    531   def __getitem__(self, key):
    532     if str(key) not in self:
--> 533       raise KeyError("Invalid split %s. Available splits are: %s" % (

Comment: I tested it on my local machine, conda environment. It works fine. My `tf` 2.4.1, and `tfds `4.2.0`

Comment: @M.Innat I'm using windows https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow with tf 2.3.0 and https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow-datasets tfds 1.2.0(the most recent updates) For issue 3, I finally found a webpage: https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/keras_example It seemed that only ds_train.batch(128) was required in order to make it work. However, tf.keras.Model.fit takes the argument " x=None, y=None, batch_size=None". But, ds_train was still a "tuple", so how come it could supply "x,y"? and wasn't batch_size supposed to be provided to Model.fit instead of the dataset pipeline ds_train?

Comment: If you can give a plug-n-play code on where you stuck that would be better to give an exact answer.  If you pass batch size from `ds_train`, there is no need to pass batch size in `.fit`.

Comment: In order to run `model.fit`, what are you using now `train_ds` or `ds` from issue 1?

Comment: @M.Innat the model.fit takes train_ds, the same as what https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/keras_example had done.

Comment: Issue 1 was answered. Issue 2 might be a bug/delay from windows' conda updates.(colab worked). Issue 3 I'm going to ask another specific question to possibly resolve this question.

Comment: @M.Innat Issue 3: I found the expiation. It's from the keras api: https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/ The iterator like object was unpacked different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue 1

About `as_supervised`, according to the doc

> bool, if True, the returned tf.data.Dataset will have a 2-tuple structure (input, label) according to builder.info.supervised_keys. If False, the default, the returned tf.data.Dataset will have a dictionary with all the features.

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

train_ds = tfds.load('mnist', split='train', as_supervised=True,shuffle_files=True)
ds = tfds.load('mnist', split='train', shuffle_files=True)

for example in ds.take(5):  
    image = example["image"]
    label = example["label"]
    print(image.shape, label.shape)

(28, 28, 1) ()
(28, 28, 1) ()
(28, 28, 1) ()
(28, 28, 1) ()
(28, 28, 1) ()

for inputs,targets in train_ds.take(5):
    print(inputs.shape, targets.shape)

(28, 28, 1) ()
(28, 28, 1) ()
(28, 28, 1) ()
(28, 28, 1) ()
(28, 28, 1) ()
```

As you have pointed out the blog [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/keras_example), states

> as_supervised: Returns tuple (img, label) instead of dict {'image': img, 'label': label}

#### Issue 2

As I stated in the comment, I tested with `TF 2.4.1` and `TF DS 4.2.0` in my local machine within an anaconda environment. And as you stated you're using `TF DS 1.2.0`, I think you should update this package. And don't rely on the `conda` package rather use the `pip` installer. It's can be possible that you can not get an updated version using the `conda` installer.

#### Issue 3

If I understand your query based on the comment, I believe you're wondering how these data can be passed to the model (`.fit`). Here I will try to use these two approaches to load data and feed it to the model.

1. Using `as_supervised=True`:

It will return a **tuple** of the training pairs (`image` and `label`). As you pointed [this document](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/keras_example), shows how to run the model with this loading approach. A `tf.data dataset` should return a **tuple** of either (`inputs`, `targets`) or (`inputs`, `targets`, `sample_weights`). However, I have a suspicion that there something wrong with the model definition there. Here is the working code:

```
ds_train, ds_info = tfds.load(
    'mnist',
    split='train',
    shuffle_files=True,
    as_supervised=True,
    with_info=True,
)

def normalize_img(image, label):
  return tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255., label

ds_train = ds_train.map(normalize_img, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
ds_train = ds_train.cache()
ds_train = ds_train.shuffle(ds_info.splits['train'].num_examples)
ds_train = ds_train.batch(128)
ds_train = ds_train.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

```
model = keras.Sequential([
                          keras.Input((28,28,1)),
                          layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
                          layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
                          layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()],
)

model.fit(
    ds_train,
    epochs=2
)

Epoch 1/2
4ms/step - loss: 2.0585 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.2354
Epoch 2/2
3ms/step - loss: 1.5647 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.4162
```

2. Using `as_supervised=False`:

By this, it will return a dictionary-like  `{'image': img, 'label': label}`. Now, according to the doc, this doesn't seem easily feedable to the model. But we can choose a workaround as follows

```
ds = tfds.load('mnist', split='train', shuffle_files=True)

train_x = []
trian_y = []

for example in ds: 
  train_x.append(example["image"])
  trian_y.append(example["label"])

train_x = np.array(train_x)
trian_y = np.array(trian_y)

print(train_x.shape, trian_y.shape)
(60000, 28, 28, 1) (60000,)
```

And using the above same model definition we can pass these training paris as follows:

```
model.fit(
    train_x,
    trian_y,
    epochs=2
)

Epoch 1/2
2ms/step - loss: 1.8551 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.4013
Epoch 2/2
2ms/step - loss: 0.7965 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.7381
```

FYI, we can pass many ways of our training pairs to the model. You can check out my other answer where we have discussed it more in detail. [Difference between using Dataset and ndarray is a `fit` method in Tensorflow 2.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66238161/9215780)