# Difference between calling the .fit() method with .fit(x_train,y_train,[...]) and .fit(train_dataset,[...])

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I can see, from the Keras documentation, that the first parameter of the fit method can be, among others:

1. a numpy array
2. a tf.data.Dataset

In case the Dataset is used, the second parameter (y) is not to be used.

The first way is pretty clear: I indicate the inputs and the labels explicitly.
I'm having trouble understanding in the second way, how can tensorflow understand which "field" is the label and which fields are the inputs.
I saw in many examples that the map function can accept a function that returns a tuple (input,label) but can also be used with only a value returned.

Is there a way, for example using from_tensor_slices, to correctly indicate where is the label, when creating a Dataset?
Thank you very much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between using Dataset and ndarray in fit method in Tensorflow 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66237656/whats-the-difference-between-using-dataset-and-ndarray-in-fit-method-in-tensorf)

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this depends on the model. A Keras model has a `train_step` method which takes a single input `data` (one batch) and runs one step of training (computing outputs, computing loss, computing & applying gradients, computing metrics). The default implementation uses

```
x, y = data
```

where `x` is used as input and `y` is used as target.
This implies that your dataset should return the same format: Each batch should be a tuple `(input, target)`. You can achieve this by creating a dataset as such:

```
data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((inputs, labels))
```

Comment: Thank you. There is still something that's unclear to me: what happens if I call that method with one only parameter, like tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 2, 3])

Comment: Then you have a dataset with only inputs, pretty much. If you try to `fit` a model, this will probably crash with the default `train_step`, since that expects inputs and labels to be there. But the best way to find out what happens, is to just try it out. :)